# MySQL 8.0.15 starts normally but any connection hangs

Tags: mysql, recovery, crash

I dropped a large table (80G) Friday morning and got a crash:

InnoDB: ###### Diagnostic info printed to the standard error stream
2019-04-19T18:48:55.445507Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012872] [InnoDB] Semaphore wait has lasted > 37617336 seconds. We intentionally crash the server because it appears to be hung.[FATAL] Semaphore wait has lasted > 600 seconds. We intentionally crash the server because it appears to be hung.
2019-04-19T18:48:55.445541Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: ut0ut.cc:625 thread 140252955932416
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
18:48:55 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

...lots more...

The server came back up and the log indicated it was ready for connections:

...

```
2019-04-22T12:53:51.792574Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.15) starting as process 26956
2019-04-22T12:53:54.631860Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting crash recovery...
2019-04-22T12:53:54.639196Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] Crash recovery finished.
2019-04-22T12:53:54.708512Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2019-04-22T12:53:54.754962Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.15'  socket: '/data/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

I tried connecting locally and remotely with mysql client, various programs, etc., but cannot complete the connection process - it just hangs. The connection protocol initiates, but then just sits there after negotiation (this is from monitoring with tcpdump):

```
10:44:02.814237 IP 10.70.250.33.snip-slave > 10.70.250.50.mysql: Flags [S], seq 3534733756, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2565739642 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:44:02.814273 IP 10.70.250.50.mysql > 10.70.250.33.snip-slave: Flags [S.], seq 4211652446, ack 3534733757, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 239668057 ecr 2565739642,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

...

```
10:44:03.042941 IP 10.70.250.50.mysql > 10.70.250.33.snip-slave: Flags [P.], seq 2784:2819, ack 858, win 252, options [nop,nop,TS val 239668286 ecr 2565739871], length 35
10:44:03.082582 IP 10.70.250.33.snip-slave > 10.70.250.50.mysql: Flags [.], ack 2819, win 160, options [nop,nop,TS val 2565739911 ecr 239668286], length 0
```

The mysqld process has been running at nearly 100% CPU, for over the weekend even, but nothing seems to change. I can't stop the server with systemd, as it'll just sit there too. I can (and have) killed the mysqld process several times today and started it back up, but again nothing seems to change. Most recently I did that to force innodb recovery, which shows in the log, but is no help since I still can't connect with *anything*.

Looking with iostat, it appears to be beating the daylights out of the general log (/dbdata/var/lib/mysql/data/mysql/general_log.CSV), which is quite large - over half a TB.

I don't really care about the table that was dropped, I just need the rest of the databases to be accessible, and I'm stuck.  Help, please!

Comment: The general log is not intended to be left on for very long.  Turn it off after you get the info you need -- this is usually minutes, not terabytes.

Answer (score 0):

Everything but the bit about the general log was a distraction. Killing the mysqld daemon, disabling the general log in my.cnf and then restarting the server worked fine. Although I can't find this documented anywhere, apparently mysqld will be completely unresponsive while it is busy prowling through it's general log, and if that log is extremely large, it can take an arbitrarily long time.

Comment: What is your 'log' rotation plan to avoid encountering such a large general log?  Dating the general log each day and keeping 30 days usually works for most installations.  In the future, you may wish to avoid installing any version with less than 6 months of 'in the field' use after General Available date to avoid discovering problems, reporting them and waiting for a resolution.

Comment: That sounds like the behavior of the InnoDB redo log, not the general query log. I'm not aware that the general query log is ever read by MySQL on startup or at any other time.